# how to calculate these intersections without having to count all combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

We have the following sets:

$X= {(a,b,c,d)  ∈S: b< c < d},$
$Y= {(a,b,c,d)  ∈S: a< c < d},$
$Z= {(a,b,c,d)  ∈S: a< b < d},$
$F= {(a,b,c,d)  ∈S: a< b < c},$
Where each of $a,b,c,d$ have integer values from  1 to 5

How to calculate $|X ∩ Y |$, $|X ∩ Z|$, $|Z ∩ F|$, $|X ∩ Y ∩ Z |$, $|X ∩ Y ∩ Z ∩ F|$ without the need to write down all possible combinations

Comment: Inclusion Exclusion Principle states $|X \cup Y| = |X| + |Y| - |X\cap Y|$ so if you can calculate X, Y and union you could use the principle and it generalizes to higher unions and intersections.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please explain how to solve it using inclusion exclusion?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but you will have to write down all possible combinations.
It's not too bad though.
For the first one, $a$ and $b$ are both less than $c$, which is less than $d$.  So $c$ is at least 3, and at most 4.  If $c=3$, there are two ways to do $a$ and $b$; for each of those there are two choices for 4.  So that makes $2\times 2$ ways if $c=3$.  If $c=4$, then $d$ must be $5$.  There are three choices for $a$, and for each of those, there are two choices for $b$.  So you work out how many ways with $c=4$.

Comment: Actually, I already tried out this way and it is working to get the right answer, but i need to solve the same problem for 1000 variables a,b,c,d,....... and each of them has values from 1 to 1000 knowing that the same value can be repeated.